# Use class names to define properties in a type

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-generics, template-literals

Let's say I have some event classes:

```
class UserCreated { ... }
class UserVerified { ... }
```

And then there's a class to handle those events:

```
class UserEventsHandler extends Something {
    onUserCreated(event) { ... }
    onUserVerified(event) { ... }
}
```

Is there a way to model such types in TypeScript? Specifically, can I somehow define required properties and methods based on class names? Here's the desired outcome:

```
type UserEvents = UserCreated | UserVerified; // ?
type EventsHandler<TEvents> = ?

// Compile-time error: 'onUserVerified' is required
class UserEventsHandler extends Something implements EventsHandler<UserEvents> {
    onUserCreated(event) { ... }
    /* onUserVerified(event) { ... } */
}
```

Compile-time template literals are obviously required for this, but I don't see the other piece of the puzzle in TypeScript, i.e. any ability to use class names to define property constraints. I'd be happy to be proven wrong though.

Comment: Do you mean to say that `EventsHandler<UserEvents>` should be an interface with property names derived from its type parameter (using names of the classes in the type parameter)?

Comment: Could you please provide more examples what you expect, for me it is a bit unclear

Comment: @Chase Might as well be an interface, yes. Of course, I could literally create a new interface and type out some properties in it with names matching those of event classes. But I'm looking for a strongly-typed DRY solution.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible, but I can't recommend using the class name for that. To make this work, you would need the type information of `UserCreated.constructor.name`. But the type of that will always be `string` and not `"UserCreated"`. Thus you need some hacky types to wrap your class with to change that, and even then, I'm not 100% sure it would be feasible, depending on your runtime code. I'll give you an example of how you could implement your wished behavior without class.name, but with a type string. You can tinker around with it to make it more suitable for your case. The key to make this work are [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types):

```
interface EventInterface {
    readonly type: string;
}

class UserCreated implements EventInterface {
    // because type is readonly, UserCreated.type resolves to "UserCreated" and not string
    type = "UserCreated";
}

type EventHandler<T extends EventInterface> = {
    // to concat strings in types you need to use template literal types
    [K in `${"on"}${T["type"]}`]: (event: T) => void;
}

// works!
class UserEventHandler implements EventHandler<UserCreated> {
   public onUserCreated(event: UserCreated) {

   }
}
// won't work
class UserEventHandlerError implements EventHandler<UserCreated> {
   public wrongFunction(event: UserCreated) {

   }
}
```

**Update: Now also contains example for multiple events at once**
[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FASwdgLgpgTgZgQwMZQAQFEBuVIElKyIqoDewqFqMUCAJgPZgA2AnqhCwA5QBcqAzhBjgA5gG5gAX2DAkTBP36oAqv1gBhagmi1UIALacmUfTghKsZ-NHjI0ZSqgD0T1ACMoSBAFc17LmggSloMzCwANCpqMJo0OgB0HNxUUPz0TNhKEPSoAESqGlo6uagIYLpg9BACQqLklCGMrP7JALx5BTFFULS5EtLASWiWkAASZbTGMAA8ACqoUAAe0OUW2HgEtigAfKjtDpQu7DlIjF7VgsJgInpgLamoLPTeqGBQPceovmjQhvLQNSuIn49QoAG0ANK3VAAAwAJCRcoxcpIEbMwbkhrkALqSGHYvgACig6wgfHmAEo9rtMPQQLR+jIZEcAO70GAAa34AEJZPJFFFYCMIONylM9H8TGY1mZRZNYNNOrFtD1dqRQZxvG4mCAkKhGErurRiaS+Ia4j0qWRQdJpKzGAByapszl8hRKTrCuVTdAwGDsiVGKWQGVjCZTRXRZU6XYHVCa7W61As-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-J980gQtCl-EsbVLCgIaTaHYBg9dN2NdL4cFGBseB5GyykIA)

Another note about `UserCreated.constructor.name`. If you plan to use this in code and not just on types, I would advise against it. If you use `UserCreated.constructor.name` on runtime to find out how the event-listener function is named, you may be badly surprised in production. The name information of `UserCreated.constructor.name` is considered debug information, and minifier don't respect it. After minification, your class will look something like this `class a_ {...}`, and now `UserCreated.constructor.name` will return the name `a_`. Thats why it's better to rely on actual strings. You could deactivate minification of function names, but this will increase bundle size quite a bit.

Comment: The use of `constructor.name` is from nestjs/cqrs in my case: https://github.com/nestjs/cqrs/blob/4fd60df196c236cb294b9b883c55e40f16fa6853/src/aggregate-root.ts#L58 Guess one should override either `getEventHandler` or `getEventName` for better minification tolerance.

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution

```
// convert an event name to a handler name
type AddOn<T extends string> = `on${Capitalize<T>}`
// convert a handler name to an event name
type RemoveOn<T extends string> = T extends `on${infer E}` ? Uncapitalize<E> : T;

// create a map of event handler from a map of events keyed by name
type EventsHandler<EventMap> = {
    [K in AddOn<Extract<keyof EventMap, string>>]: 
        RemoveOn<K> extends keyof EventMap ? (event: EventMap[RemoveOn<K>]) => void : never;
}
```

---

#### Explanation

@Micro S. has given you an excellent answer with a name-based solution. An alternative approach that you might consider is using a map-based approach.

There are many functions in DOM library that have to match an event name such as `"click"` to a specific event type such as `MouseEvent`.  The event types are not unique for every event.  A "click" event has all of the same information as a "mousedown" event.

If you look at how this is handled in `lib.dom.ts` you will see that they define these relationships using maps.  Lots and lots of maps (67 of them), many of which extend each other.  Each map describes the events associated with a particular object or interface. For example there is an [`interface DocumentEventMap`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/ec77bff33226fb01f4e38b20e481f8c1fcd9e6c0/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L4464) for a `Document` which extends the universal events [`interface GlobalEventHandlersEventMap`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/ec77bff33226fb01f4e38b20e481f8c1fcd9e6c0/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L5772) and also extends [`interface DocumentAndElementEventHandlersEventMap`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/ec77bff33226fb01f4e38b20e481f8c1fcd9e6c0/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L4952) which includes the events that are shared by documents and HTML elements so that they don't need to be written out twice.

So instead of defining a union:

```
type UserEvents = UserCreated | UserVerified;
```

We want to define a mapping:

```
interface UserEvents {
    userCreated: UserCreated;
    userVerified: UserVerified;
}
```

Now we can work some Typescript magic with the new [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html) along with [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) to create your `EventsHandler` type.

We can create generic template literals to convert a key `"userCreated"` to a method name `"onUserCreated"` and back.

```
type AddOn<T extends string> = `on${Capitalize<T>}`
type RemoveOn<T extends string> = T extends `on${infer E}` ? Uncapitalize<E> : T;

type A = AddOn<'userCreated'> // type: "onUserCreated"
type B = RemoveOn<'onUserCreated'> // type: "userCreated"
```

We want our keys of our `EventsHandler` to be the `AddOn` version.  We can apply the type `AddOn` to a union of strings and get a union of their mapped versions.  This requires that the keys must be a `string` so we use `Extract<keyof EventMap, string>` for that.

This is our key type:

```
type C = AddOn<Extract<keyof UserEvents, string>> // type: "onUserCreated" | "onUserVerified"
```

If our mapped interface uses the `AddOn` version as the keys, then we need to use `RemoveOn` to go back to the original keys.  We know that this is the inverse and therefore `RemoveOn<K>` should be a key of the `EventMap` that we derived `K` from, but Typescript will not make that assumption so we have to double check with `extends`.

```
type EventsHandler<EventMap> = {
    [K in AddOn<Extract<keyof EventMap, string>>]: RemoveOn<K> extends keyof EventMap ? (event: EventMap[RemoveOn<K>]) => void : never;
}
```

Applying this type to our `interface UserEvents` gives us the desired result:

```
type D = EventsHandler<UserEvents>
```

resolves to:

```
type D = {
    onUserCreated: (event: UserCreated) => void;
    onUserVerified: (event: UserVerified) => void;
}
```

Now we get the error that we are after:

> Class 'UserEventsHandler' incorrectly implements interface 'EventsHandler'.
>
> Property 'onUserVerified' is missing in type 'UserEventsHandler' but required in type 'EventsHandler'.

Annoyingly, you still have to define the type for the `event` variable in your methods.  You will get errors if you assign an invalid type for your `event`.  An invalid type would be one that requires properties which are not present in our expected event type, but it's fine to require only a subset of the event `onUserVerified(event: {})` or no event at all `onUserVerified()` as these will both work when called with a `UserVerified` event.

Note that I have kept all the names the same as in your example, but the names of the events in the map do not have to match the name of the event `class`.  This is fine too:

```
class UserEvent {
}

interface UserEventsMap {
    created: UserEvent;
    verified: UserEvent;
}

class UserEventsHandler2 implements EventsHandler<UserEventsMap> {
    onCreated(event: UserEvent) { }
    onVerified(event: UserEvent) {  }
}
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/wQA8Gw)